# Get URL of Website from where Web Service Call is Made

Tags: c#, web-services, url

In my web service, how can I check the URL of the web site from where the web service call originated please?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean A) the IP of the client accessing the web service, B)some referral URL that transferred the client to the web services, C) The hosting/page URL that some client application (say, Silverlight) is running in, D) other?

Comment: like option A but instead of the IP, I want the URL

Comment: You want the web page then from where the request came from? The call is made via AJAX/javascript then?

Comment: Does `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` work in this context for you?

Comment: No.  I have a client app which makes a request to a server in the form of a web service.  I want the web page on the client app from where the call to the web service was made.  I am using C#

Comment: What kind of client app? If you're making the call using a direct API like `HttpWebRequest`, then I don't think a referral URL is sent.

Comment: I am consuming a web service asmx on the client app

Comment: _What kind of client app?_ What platform is it? _How_ are you consuming the asmx web service?

Comment: the client app is a web appkication deployed on IIS.  It is written in .NET and the web service calls are being made by importing a web reference of the web service.  I edited the host file such that the client app can use the domain www.test.com

Comment: the web app hosting the web service is deployed on iis as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario I think you have a web application hosted in IIS and that web application is consuming asmx web services and you need to get the name of the page which called the service in the service implementation.

The ASMX webservices are not limited to access from the web sites. They can be accessed from the desktop applications as well which don't have webpage url. So in this context we expect to  get the web page URL as is inside the web service implementation. You may get the IP address of the caller machine. But seems that is not enough.

So only way is to pass the name of the webpage from the calling code via parameter or http header.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  So I have to rely on the honesty of the client who passes the correct web address.  Am I right?

Comment: I tried getting the request IP address.  Now, since both apps are deployed on my machine, I expected the IP to be 127.0.0.1 but all I got was ::1?  Why is this?

Comment: @Matthew That's the IPv6 version of 127.0.0.1

Comment: If you are calling the web service from jQuery / javascript,yes you need to rely. If its originating from asp.net code behind,I don't think you need to validate as the request itself is from your code. What is the security mechanism using in the web service? You can also block the calls from other site origins using policies I believe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy ..

Comment: I don't think you understood me correctly.  Even though I am running the client on my machine, in a real-life scenario it would be a separate machine.  However, I have to do a demonstration on my laptop so I have to cram everything on one machine.

Comment: Yes in real time it would be different machine.But if its from javascript, using the site origin policies we can control the callers I believe. By the by are you calling your web services from javascript/jQuery or completely from web site (C#/VB.Net)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're asking is for the requesting URL of the Web service called.

webpage.aspx -- (calls )  -->  MyWebService.asmx.

the referrer is webpage.aspx

Try using Context.Request.UrlReferrer from the webservice.